# How to include opos service objects and controls in c# application?

Tags: c#, opos

- I Want to write a small **C#** application using the **OPOS** Controls communicating through **serial comm port**.
- I have the **OPOS dll**.
- I have installed **OPOS CommonControlObjects**.
- To use the instance of this controls in my application How should I include these controls in the app.
- (For eg:  I want to include `MSR, SigCap controls` similar to a button control in my app) or can they be included as components in my project. If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your toolbox and Right-click on it.

Then select -Choose Items-.

Having done this, browse to your folders to find your OPOS DLL.

Last, add the items you want.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I already registered the controls previously. So as u said, i browsed to that and added the controls which i want.